# R: how (not to) filter in shinydashboard

Tags: r, shinydashboard

This is a very simple shinydashboard:

```
# Load libraries
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(tidyverse)

data <- data.frame(sex = sample(c("Male", "Female"), size=100, replace=TRUE),
                   smoker = sample(c("yes", "no"), size=100, replace=TRUE))

## UI ##
ui <- dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(
        title = "My Dashboard"
    ),
    dashboardSidebar(
        sidebarMenu(
            
        )
        
    ),
    dashboardBody(
        box(
            title="Barplot", status='primary', solidHeader = T,
            plotOutput("myBarplot")
        ),
        box(
            title="Filter", status='warning', solidHeader = T,
            selectInput("findSex", "Choose sex:", c("All", "Male", "Female"))
        )              
    )
)
    
        

## Server ##
server <- function(input, output){
    set.seed(122)
    
    filtered_df <- reactive({
        data <- data %>% filter(sex == input$findSex)
        data})
    
    output$myBarplot <- renderPlot({
        filtered_df() %>% ggplot(aes(x = smoker)) + geom_bar()  + ylab("Prozente")
    })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

The dashboard displays the number of smokers/non-smokers and you can filter by sex. This is implemented as follows:

```
        data <- data %>% filter(sex == input$findSex)
```

Now I have two questions:

- How can I by default display ALL cases (male AND female)?
- How can I display ALL cases again after males or females have been selected? (is there something like `filter(sex == '*')` in R? And is there a way to distinguish between a label and a value when using `selectInput()`? (e.g. in HTML you can have `<select><option value='1'>Male</option> <option value='2'>Female</option></select>`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could transform `'All'` in `c('Male','Female')` and use `%in%` :

```
  filtered_df <- reactive({
    if (input$findSex == "All") {
       sexSelect <- c('Male','Female')
    }
    else {
       sexSelect <- input$findSex
    }
    data %>% filter(sex %in% sexSelect)
    })
```

Comment: Your second question actually contains two questions. 
The first part, you can use something like this to select all the observations
`filter(df, TRUE)` or `filter(df, sex %in% sex)`.

For the second part, you can use named vectors. For example 
selectInput("myinput", "Input", c("label1" = "value1", "label2" = "value2")) will show the options "label1" and "label2" but the values you access with input$myinput are "value1" and "value2".

Comment: And I agree with @Waldi on the answer to the first question.